# Comic: a frontiersman and his Mexican sidekick fight a sect of Aztec mummies

Tags: story-identification, comics, western

Comic book, possibly American, from the early 1970s, in black and white. A Davy-Crocket-style frontiersman whose weapon of choice is an axe, has a Mexican sidekick with certain similarities to Sancho Panza—small, chubby, and antiheroic.

I think it was a regular collection. In the issue I remember our heroes were somewhere in Mexico or in the desert areas of the USA closer to the border. There was some sort of hidden valley where a sect of hooded men lived in an old medieval Spanish castle. They oppressed a tribe of Indians and killed people by shooting them with their blowguns, using some kind of poison that turned their victims into mummies.

Later in the comic it is discovered that the hooded men were also living mummies, from some pre-Columbian civilization, perhaps the Aztecs. There was also a band of Mexican bandits who were somewhat allied with the mummy men.

Comment: I guess it's not Quick-Draw McGraw....

Comment: @Spencer The sidekick seems correct but I don't recall seeing the hero using an axe.. ;)

Comment: [Ohhhhhhhhh...., reallllly? You don't say.....](https://youtu.be/010aaw1Ajo0)